# Android Camera2 API - lack of privileges on resume

Tags: android, android-permissions, camera2

I'm developing the app using Camera2 API. My problem looks like that:
 when I hit the device's sleep button while the camera fragment is working and after that I wake up the device, the application restarts

```
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app, PID: 5081
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app/com.snapsportz.handheldcamera.app.CameraActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Lacking privileges to access camera service
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3381)
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3340)
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4047)
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java)
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1350)
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Lacking privileges to access camera service
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.hardware.camera2.utils.CameraBinderDecorator.throwOnError(CameraBinderDecorator.java:108)
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.hardware.camera2.utils.CameraBinderDecorator$CameraBinderDecoratorListener.onAfterInvocation(CameraBinderDecorator.java:73)
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.hardware.camera2.utils.Decorator.invoke(Decorator.java:81)
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at $Proxy1.cancelRequest(Unknown Source)
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.stopRepeating(CameraDeviceImpl.java:899)
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.close(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:373)
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.snapsportz.handheldcamera.app.Camera2BasicFragment.closeCamera(Camera2BasicFragment.java:899)
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.snapsportz.handheldcamera.app.Camera2BasicFragment.onPause(Camera2BasicFragment.java:771)
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Fragment.performPause(Fragment.java:2379)
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1019)
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1130)
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchPause(FragmentManager.java:1967)
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentController.dispatchPause(FragmentController.java:185)
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:6346)
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1311)
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3367)
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3340) 
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4047) 
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java) 
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1350) 
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
12-10 10:59:10.423 5081-5081/com.snapsportz.nexus5camera.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I believe that it's not a lack of camera permission in manifest file because it is included in it and the app works fine unless I try to wake it up.

I'll be really glad for any hint.

Comment: You got both? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> and <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" /> ?

Comment: yes I've got both of them

Comment: Google's official Sample App for Camera2 has the same issue: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/issues/42

Comment: The comments from Google in the Chromium browser source code imply this is a "undocumented Exception", reference: https://1252-00bb8fd8c843-dot-chromiumcodereview-hr.appspot.com/1910793002/

Answer (score 2):

If you used the Google Camera2Basic Sample App - [issue #42](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/issues/42) seems to describe the problem. The solution is to review your use of `onResume` method in your `Fragment` - and call `closeCamera()` before you call `openCamera()` in the `onResume()`.  Seems to fix the problem in my testing of `Camera2Basic`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, It's because you didn't stop the camera device.
I solved this in onPause/onResume activity override methods:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.e(TAG, "onResume");
    ...
    openCamera();
    ...
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onPause");
    closeCamera();
    super.onPause();
}
```

This worked for me.

Regards.-